# scratch sprite not registering hit consistently

Tags: sprite, mit-scratch

This simple shooter game is supposed to result in the sprite shattering and disappearing when hit. It will work maybe 40% of the time. Here's the link to the project and the relevant code block:

https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/524150880/editor

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So turns out that by simplifyingthe sprite's movements from:
[image]

to:

[image]

fixed the problem. Sprite consistently breaks up and disappears when hit. So it was just a matter of streamlining I guess?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to make a shooter game, you probably want to use `create clone of [myself]` block and then do this:
`when i start as a clone`
`show`
`repeat until < <touching [YOUR TARGET SPRITE HERE]> or <touching [edge]> >`
`|| point in direction (DIRECTION OF YOUR SHOOTER)`
`|| move (ADD YOUR NUMBER HERE)`
`start sound (meow)`
`change [score] by (1)`
`repeat (5)`
`|| change [mosaic] effect by (2)`
`delete this clone`

For the bullet, you would need this script:
`when green flag clicked`
`forever`
`if <key [ANY KEY YOU WOULD LIKE TO USE TO SHOOT] pressed> then`
`|| create clone of myself`

However if you would like to add a cooldown to the bullets, make a new variable called `cooldown` and reduce it by 0.1 every millisecond (0.1 second), but do make sure that when cooldown is 0 it doesn't go into the negatives, and when cooldown is 0, you can shoot and it resets the cooldown to the number of seconds you want it to be, if you want it your code should look like this:

`when green flag clicked`
`forever`
`if <key [ANY KEY YOU WOULD LIKE TO USE TO SHOOT] pressed> then`
`|| if cooldown < 0.1`
`|| || create clone of myself`

The reason it is `|| if cooldown < 0.1` and not `|| if cooldown = 0` is because if you screw up and accidentally make it 4.25 instead of 4.2 the bullet would still shoot

Comment: Sorry but this time, sprite doesn't shatter or disappear at all. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Did you remember to put ```delete this clone```? If you didn't it won't delete the clone of your bullet. Are you confused by the formatting?

Comment: I did delete the clone and I did pick up on your formatting. If the code were wrong then it would be wrong all the time, not just part of the time. I hate to say scratch is buggy since I've always believed the computer is never wrong, but I'm going in that direction.

Comment: Hey! I'm sorry for only replying after 5 months, but you would need to delete your old code for it to work.

Comment: Better late than never, thanks! It's working pretty much as it should after I streamlined the code.